# PHP script stops processing input file after 5 seconds

Tags: php, nginx

I've written a PHP script that takes in two CSV files, processes them and returns an HTML table. I developed it on my MacBook running on Apache. When I uploaded the script to our production server, it began having problems. Production is an Ubuntu 10.04 LTS running nginx that forwards requests to Apache/PHP.

I added some debugging statements and tailed the logs so I can see exactly where it's stopping the execution of the script, but there are no errors thrown anywhere. The first file is 1.9 MB and it processes 366 kb before it fails. I've tested this several times and it always fails at the same place. I don't believe it's the file as it's the same file I used for testing the script and it never had a problem on my MacBook.

I've searched the internet and have increased several timeout parameters in nginx to no avail. I'm not sure where to look or what to look for at this point. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: have you fully turned on error reporting on the server?

Comment: please post some code? Also what permissions are on the file(s) and what user is running the script might be an issue as well. Make sure the user can read the file(s)

Comment: Kind of hard to help without any code to go off of.

Comment: first test a different file to import, that will tell you if that's the file or something else. if you still have the issue, post code :)

Comment: Thanks, @seengee. I thought I had fully turned on error reporting, but I hadn't. I turned it on and found it was a memory issue. I checked php.ini and memory_limit was set for 16mb. I upped it to 128mb and it processed everything easily.

Comment: i'll make my comment an answer so this question can be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you fully turned on error reporting on the server?